# Javascript function executes only after second hover

Tags: javascript, function

I have got a small javascript function and a piece of html code where i have a button, and I want that whenever user hovers that button, a little box to appear.Everything seems to be working great,despite that my function executes only after I hover that button for the 2 time(after the page has just loaded and I try to use my function for the 1 time, later everything executes after a firs hover).So what can I do about it?
HTML code

```
<body>
<div id = "searchBox">
    <p id = "paragraph"><input type = "text" name = "serachBar"/>
    <input type = "button" value = "szukaj" name = "search"/>
    </p>
    <div id = "searchButton"><a href = "#" onmouseover="popUp('paragraph')">Szukaj</a></div>
</div>
</body>
```

and javascript itself

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function popUp(menu){
    var searchBox = document.getElementById(menu).style;
    var searcButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
    if(!searchBox || searchBox.display == "none"){
        searchBox.display = "block";
        }
    else {
        searchBox.display = "none";
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `if` statement like this:

```
function popUp(menu) {
    var searchBox = document.getElementById(menu);
    var searcButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
    if (searchBox) {
        if(searchBox.style.display == ""){
            searchBox.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            searchBox.style.display = "";
        }
    }
};
```

The original value will be `""` instead of `"none"`.

I'm making the assumption that the CSS setting is to `display:"none"`.

I also moved the `searchBox` condition. If it isn't found, you don't want to set properties at all.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that the `style` object itself is always a truthy value for being an object.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Ah, yeah, I caught that a little late.

Comment: +1 makes perfect sense. I assume OP will not have elements that aren't found, otherwise it'd return an error upon trying to access a `style` property of `null` at `document.getElementById(menu).style`. **edit:** Oh, your updated version accounts for that too.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yeah, I just updated that again. It was messing with my head having a style object in a variable named `searchBox`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` is a flow element and can't contain `<input>s`.

Besides, your function instructs to toggle hidden state, rather than show box on mouseover.  Therefore, the box will hide on first hover, and reappear on the second one.

You probably want to define `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners.